# How to debug PAS file from C++ Builder? (E2468 Value of type void is not allowed)

Tags: delphi, debugging, c++builder

I have a C++ project that also includes some Delphi files (custom code).
While debugging, I want to be able to step into the pas file and inspect the variables.
However, when I add a (pascal) string variable to the Watch List, the debugger says "E2468 Value of type void is not allowed".

```
function EnterToCRLF (CONST Text: string): string;   
begin
 Result:= StringReplace(Text  , CR, 'CR', [rfReplaceAll]);  
 Result:= StringReplace(Result, LF, 'LF', [rfReplaceAll]);   
end;
```

If I put a breakpoint of the second line, the debugger stops but I can't see the value of 'text' or 'result'.

In C++ Builder, the settings for the Delphi compiler are properly set for debugging. This means they are identical to the settings I have in Delphi, where debugging works.

[image]

Comment: There's not enough information here. You can step into Delphi source just fine, if you're using debug .dcus. Sample code that includes the *(pascal) string variable* in the context it's being used would be helpful.

Comment: @KenWhite - requested code added. but the problem cannot be related to the code, but rather to the way the C++ debugger works, OR to the way the debugging information was added to the EXE file.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out.  It's annoying as heck.

Comment: @user3161924 - No. Sorry. I abandoned C++ and never worked with it since then.